# Problem with image_transport callback

Tags: ros, callbacks, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the next scenario,

```
class controller :
        {
        public:
            controller(ros::NodeHandle node);
            ~controller(void);
            // The callbacks are implemented correctly
            void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg);
            void navdataCallback(const ardrone_autonomy::Navdata& data);
            void foo(){
                // Do Something
                std::thread foo_thread(&controller::foo2, this);
                foo_thread.join();
            }
            void foo2(){
                // Do Something
                while (something){
                    // Do Something
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
                    ros::spinOnce();
                }
            }
       private:
            //Other Stuff
    }
```

and the main program is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc,argv, "main");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  controller control(n);
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub   = it.subscribe("ardrone/image_raw", 1, &controller::imageCallback, &control);
  ros::Subscriber navdata           = n.subscribe("ardrone/navdata", 1000, &controller::navdataCallback, &control);
  while(ros::ok()){
    ros::spin();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the problem is when I process data in foo2() the navdata messages arrives fine, but stop reciving image data until the end of the thread.

How can I resolve this? Is my approach correct? May be the ros::spinOnce is not placed correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252207/problem-with-image_transport-callback/) by [Abind](https://answers.ros.org/users/29083/abind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer my own question, is not a good idea use ros::spin in diferents threads, you need to use multi thread spining.

So, in order to solve this I just put all the callbacks in a different thread, so I just need to use ros::spin in just one thread and problem solved :)

---

Originally posted by [Abind](https://answers.ros.org/users/29083/abind/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0